Postgresql Procedure not getting called from spring boot 3.3 but database connection has established successfully
I am not able to call a stored procedure from Spring Boot 3.3, but I am able to establish a database connection use fetch queries.
When calling the stored procedure, I am getting this error:
Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults 
[ERROR: procedure def.abc(character varying, character varying) does not exist
Hint: No procedure matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type
casts. Position: 6] 
[HikariProxyCallableStatement@2039624079 wrapping call def.abc(('10107'),('10107'))];
SQL [HikariProxyCallableStatement@2039624079 wrapping call def.abc(('10107'),('10107'))]

I have created the stored procedure in postgresDB like this: def.abc(code character varying, pincode character varying)
